# Windows 10 auto toggle off wifi connection on cable connection

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-10, ethernet

I have a new installed Windows 10 laptop with a strange network behaviour.
(Preamble: the manual wifi switch is on. The driver is correct (MS driver). The wifi device "allow to turn-off" is disabled)

When I use the cable ethernet connection I can't switch on the WiFi access (card is online and enabled in device manager but not connected and there's no way to enable it from wifi settings).

If I un-plug the cable, after 30 secs, the wifi is being auto switched ON and ready to connect (and 100% works if configured), but if I re-plug the cable in the Wifi returns OFF after few secs.

If I disable the cable card from device manager (with the cable in) again the WiFi refuses to go online.

Is there a way to configure a different auto-switching method?
Is there a way to use both cards at the same time (as in windows 7 or 8)?

Thank you
Lox

Answer (score 2):

What model do you have and does it have factory software installed?
Dell has a feature on their laptops that will auto-disconnect when Ethernet is plugged in.

Comment: In fact is a Dell. BIOS? Thank you for your hint

Comment: @LoxLox It is possible. I know that some Models have that option on bios where others it is done through their software.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly late to the party but have a look at this link:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/mobilebroadband/understanding-and-configuring-windows-connection-manager

Windows from 8 has default behaviour to not connect to a WiFi network if it's already on a LAN.

You can change settings though to allow a different behaviour.